# Return address of first error cell found (between A1 and X500)

Tags: vba, excel

If you got a way, give me a bit of a breakdown so I can learn it instead of just copying it. -Thx

```
=ADDRESS(MATCH("keyword",B:B,0),3,1,1)
```

This handy thing nets me things I'm looking for in a column and I can adjust it to work for 1 column but it seems searching for errors in multiple columns and rows is above my pay grade.

............
**For those interested in the how to**:

You can further help your self by links to the address you get with your searches... (It reallly handy jumping to spots of interest provided your document doesn't require you to leave errors behind, so you can't get to the next one this way)

(example searches)

Simple version

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("#",a1),"Title of Link")
```

It sends you to whatever address it finds in A1 when clicked (if you want to enter the cell holding the link just hold leftclick longer.)

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("#",CELL("Address",INDEX($B:$B,MATCH
("keyword your search for",$B:$B,0)+0))),"Title of Link")
```

breakdown:
hyperlink, # = internal link - to this file or sheet(whatever it was), use address, found by index match criteria, name - what text appears in the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tony Valko of the www.excelforum.com has nailed this with a master stroke - Here it is for anybody else who wants to use it:

```
=IFERROR(ADDRESS(MOD(SMALL(IF(ISERROR($A$1:$D$5),COLUMN($A$1:$D$5)*10000+ROW($A$1:$D$5)),ROWS(F$1:F1)),10000),TRUNC(SMALL(IF(ISERROR($A$1:$D$5),COLUMN($A$1:$D$5)*10000+ROW($A$1:$D$5)),ROWS(F$1:F1))/10000),4),"")
```

** array formulas need to be entered using the key
combination of CTRL,SHIFT,ENTER (not just ENTER).
Hold down both the CTRL key and the SHIFT key.

Additionally you can substitute the end "") with "Some word") to not lose the formula from view when you have no errors..

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend using full column references with the [AGGREGATE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) but cutting down the column references to a more reasonable representation of your actual data area works well.

```
'first error
=ADDRESS(AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(1:9999)/ISERROR(B1:B9999), 1), COLUMN(B:B), 1, 1)
'second error
=ADDRESS(AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(1:9999)/ISERROR(B1:B9999), 2), COLUMN(B:B), 1, 1)
'last error
=ADDRESS(AGGREGATE(14, 6, ROW(1:9999)/ISERROR(B1:B9999), 1), COLUMN(B:B), 1, 1)

'first error in column B:D from B1, B2, ... D9998, D9999
=IFERROR(ADDRESS(AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(1:9999)/ISERROR(B1:B9999), 1), COLUMN(B:B), 1, 1),
  IFERROR(ADDRESS(AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(1:9999)/ISERROR(C1:C9999), 1), COLUMN(C:C), 1, 1),
  IFERROR(ADDRESS(AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(1:9999)/ISERROR(D1:D9999), 1), COLUMN(D:D), 1, 1), "no errors")))
```

In the last example the [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) is used to pass control over to the next sub-formula referencing another column if no errors are found.

[image: Address of first and last error]

---

¹ <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>

Comment: You are way ahead of me, how do i make it look in B1 to D500? I'm reading the info on the function but it will take me a while to grasp it ... (and yeah i cut the ranges down, people just read neat references better than AD1345 to CS4214.)

Comment: I've stacked three together with the [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5). See above addendum.

Comment: It works as a last resort I guess, but I'm sure I've seen people use clever matches to search wider ranges without actually stacking individual column searches like you and I do. Its possible this can only be done crudely without VBA. We'll see.